# Cucumber on the eyes

Tags: human-anatomy

In many spas and salons I have seen people place a cold cucumber on their eyes.
 I think this might be for coolness, but why a cucumber?
And Is it actually for coolness or for something else (like lightening of dark circles, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

> Cucumbers have an anti-inflammatory effect that reduces puffiness. The
>   vegetable not only has a high water content, it but it's often stored
>   in the refrigerator and comes out cold. This means that the water
>   hydrates your skin, and the cool temperature decreases the flow of
>   blood to the space around your eyes. Together, additional hydration
>   and reduced blood flow can sooth the skin around your eyes and
>   alleviate swelling

[Source](http://health.howstuffworks.com/skin-care/moisturizing/products/cucumbers-for-eyes.htm)

Also it has silica.

Comment: ...What does the silica do? It'd also be appreciated if your answer wasn't entirely a direct quote from the article.

Comment: @Lance made it cw.

Comment: @Mahmud can u please provide some more info?